# Hovermode using Plotly with R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, hover, plotly

Is there a way to code the hovermode when using plotly with R and ggplot2?

Currently, my code is:

```
plot <- ggplot(data, aes(var1, var2, text=var3)) + 
  geom_point()
py$ggplotly(plot)
```

And I want the plotly graph to automatically have the hover mode set to "show closest data on hover" rather than "compare data on hover".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following argument when calling `ggplotly`:

```
py$ggplotly(plot, kwargs=list(layout=list(hovermode="closest")))
```

Comment: It works well with an unfaceted graph, but as soon as I add facets, the graph doesn't appear as normal. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: What exactly is broken or missing?  Could you please show code and/or plots?

Answer (score 7):

The answer from 'mkcor' didn't work when trying to do the same in Shiny. I kept getting an 'unused argument' error. For anyone else with the same problem, this worked for me...

Suppose this is my basic plot:

```
p <- ggplot(myDf, aes(x=x, y=y )) + geom_point(size = 3, shape = 0)
```

You can convert the ggplot object to a plotly object:

```
ggObj <- plotly(p)
```

Then you can change the hovermode like this:

```
layout(ggObj, hovermode = 'closest')
```

Comment: Fantastic! I'd have never figured this out :).